# What does "provided the translations" mean?

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of:

> I provided the translations of quotations from non-English sources

Does it mean, "I translated the quotations"?

Comment: Not necessarily. It means exactly what it says: "I provided the translations". I could have found others' translations and provided them for publication; I could have requested others to do the translations; and I could have done the translations myself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are citing sources in foreign languages in your own work, there is a strong presumption that you can read them yourself. Therefore, the normal expectation is that the translations you provide are also your own work. Nevertheless, the sentence *I provided the translations of quotations from non-English sources* offers no explicit clue as to who translated the sources. If this is in a research paper of some kind, then the reader should be able to tell whether a translation is from your own hand or from that of someone else, because you will cite it accordingly. For example, you may write "my translation" (or "translation is original to this study" if you are using a style that permits no self-references) or instead something like "translation from Jones..." (followed by the rest of the citation, according to the style that you are using). It makes sense to use a preexisting translation in biblical studies or classics that have well-established translations available; otherwise, if you are claiming to have read the work in its original language, then it is best to demonstrate that capacity by also providing your own translations in your own writing.